# Android Studio - ¿Por que no puedo activar/desactivar un Radio Button programáticamente?

Tags: android, android-studio, radiobutton

Quiero activar o desactivar según corresponda, un Radio Button pero por medio de código.

**Esto es lo que estoy intentando:**

```
radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!radioButton.isChecked()){
                radioButton.setChecked(true);
            }
            else if(radioButton.isChecked()){
                radioButton.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

**Problema:**

Lo que ocurre al ejecutar este código, es que al clickear en el radio Button, este se activa y desactiva automáticamente. Es decir que hace el efecto de activación pero al final no pasa nada. Agradecería mucho la resolución de esto!

Comment: y si usan un CheckBox?

Comment: NO quiero......

Comment: Hola Tomas a que te refieres con " al final no pasa nada." , si ves que se activa/desactiva pero después que sucede?

Comment: Hace el efecto de activación pero no se activa. Es decir que al tocarlo, no se activa ni se desactiva

Comment: Si estás utilizando un `RadioButton` independiente de un `RadioGroup`, por temas de usabilidad, **no debes cambiar el comportamiento de los componentes**, lo ideal es utilizar un Checkbox para lograr lo que quieres que me imagino que es verificar la casilla. En todo caso si lo que quieres es ir en contra de la naturaleza de los componentes de Android, puedes utilizar un RadioGroup como padre del RadioButton y utilizar `radioGroup.clearCheck()` para limpiar la selección antes de hacer setChecked o crear un selector con los estados que quieres. Hay muchos ejemplos en la web.

Comment: La usabilidad es importante como requerimiento no funcional, y, a menos que sea un requerimiento del cliente como diseño, no te recomiendo utilizar `RadioButton` pues tiende a confundir al usuario porque son reglas de diseño que ya han sido verificadas en el mercado. De todos modos puedes darle el estilo que quieras que se adapte a lo que el cliente quiere o su línea de diseño.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que usar un `CheckBox`, ya que los `RadioButton` tienen una funcionalidad concreta.
Que consiste en que se agrupan varios en un `RadioGroup` y de éstos solo permite seleccionar uno.

Si necesitas otra cosa mejor `CheckBox`.

Y puedes simplificar esa instrucción así:

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
    }
});
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Un saludo

Mauri

Lección del mes: [¿Qué son y para qué sirven los DP en Android?](https://tyris-software.com/que-son-y-para-que-sirven-los-dp-en-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Comprendo perfectamente tu problema. Yo tuve el mismo. Es cierto que un checkBox parece más apropiado para determinadas cosas pero lo que yo quería era una opción (y solo una) que se pudiese seleccionar o dejar en blanco. El problema era que una vez seleccionada una opción ya no podías dejarla en blanco. Para eso puedes poner un radioButton extra con el valor "No responder", por ejemplo. O bien usar lo que yo:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(v.getId());
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (rb.isChecked()) {
                desactivar = true;
            }
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (desactivar) {
                rb.setEnabled(false);
                RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) rb.getParent();
                rg.clearCheck();
                desactivar = false;
                rb.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Sobreescribes onTouch para controlar los eventos de pulsación (abajo y arriba). Con eso controlas perfectamente los momentos de activado y desactivado del botón.
Me parece que el listado está claro y no debería costar mucho entenderlo. A mí me fue perfecto porque tenía muchos grupos de radioButton diferentes y no quería añadir botones extra para anular una pulsación ya realizada.

Espero que a alguien le sirva.